# How to convert DataTable to Array in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert `DataTable` `datatable1` to `Multidimensional Array` in `C#`:

```
|  Name  |  Age  |
------------------
|  jim   |   23  |
|  ard   |   22  |
|  tom   |   30  |
```

I want to convert that to `[["jim",23],["ard",22],["tom",30]]`.
Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: array with size 2x3

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be :

```
string[,] str = new string[YourDataTable.Rows.Count, 2]; 

int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)
{
    if (i < YourDataTable.Rows.Count)
    {
        str[i, 1] = row["name"].ToString();
        str[i, 2] = row["age"].ToString();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a way. Take my upvote. It seems, the questioner does not appreciate the time one spends to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var datatable1 = CreateDataTable(); // or the way you populate the table
var data = datatable1.Rows
                     .Cast<DataRow>()
                     .Select(row => row.ItemArray)
                     .ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(DataToString(data));
```

Where `CreateDataTable()` is

```
DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    var dt = new DataTable("tbl");
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Age", typeof(int))
    });
    dt.Rows.Add("Jim", 23);
    dt.Rows.Add("Ard", 22);
    dt.Rows.Add("Tom", 30);
    return dt;
}
```

And `DataToString(object[][] data)` is

```
string DataToString(object[][] data) =>
    $"[{string.Join(", ", data.Select(i => $"[{string.Join(", ", i)}]"))}]";
```

Gives

```
[[Jim, 23], [Ard, 22], [Tom, 30]]
```